# Separating XML Values

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am working in .Net and Oracle. I am having a XML data in my table. My data is like this..

```
<Goals>
    <Reg>
        <Min>75</Min>
        <Max>90</Max>
    </Reg>
    <Sale>
        <Min>75</Min>
        <Max>90</Max>
    </Sale>
</Goals>
```

also have some other columns in that table. I need to fetch this and I should bind this value in gridview. My gridview will have separate columns for these XML. like, Reg Min, Reg Max, Sale Min,Sale Max etc..

How should I separate this XML values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it in the DB:

```
select t.id,
       xmltype(t.xmltext) .extract('//Reg/Min/text()').getstringval() reg_min,
       xmltype(t.xmltext) .extract('//Reg/Max/text()').getstringval() reg_max,
       xmltype(t.xmltext) .extract('//Sale/Min/text()').getstringval() sale_min,
       xmltype(t.xmltext) .extract('//Sale/Max/text()').getstringval() sale_max
  from table_name t
```

I used `table_name` as your table name, and `xmltext` as the column name which holds your xml (assuming it's a string)

Comment: By using this query i am not getting th values in reg min,reg max, sale min and sale max columns...  SELECT T.ID, 
       XMLTYPE(T.DEFAULT_VALUES) .EXTRACT('//Reg/min/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() REG_MIN, 
       XMLTYPE(T.DEFAULT_VALUES) .EXTRACT('//Reg/max/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() REG_MAX, 
       XMLTYPE(T.DEFAULT_VALUES) .EXTRACT('//Sale/min/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() SALE_MIN, 
       XMLTYPE(T.DEFAULT_VALUES) .EXTRACT('//Sale/max/text()').GETSTRINGVAL() SALE_MAX 
  FROM TableName T

Comment: Maybe because I wrote `min` `max` instead of `Min` `Max`. I updated my answer, try it now

Comment: Exactly..I dint notice that..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx),

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
string max = (string)doc.Root.Element("Reg").Element("Max");//return Max
```